# wordpress child theme styles.css does not want to override parent style.css

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

My child theme `styles.css` does not want to override parent `style.css.`

I am working with the `wordpress theme twenty fourteen` .

I have created a child theme, and through research have found the following piece of code...

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/my_included_file.php' );
```

My question is where exactly does this code go? I read in the `functions.php`. So do I put it in the first line of the page.
I want my child theme stylesheet to take priority over my parent stylesheet.

Thank you any help would be great..

Answer (score 0):

You should not need that code. Once you activate the child theme, that stylesheet will be included after the parent theme's and will therefore override those in the parent theme’s stylesheet.

Read more about [Child Themes at the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly import your parent-theme `style.css` by `@import url('../parent-theme-name/style.css');` in your child-theme `style.css` and below it write your own css code or override the parent-theme css code.

you can also use this plugin to create child theme http://wordpress.org/plugins/orbisius-child-theme-creator/